# click on image in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode, interface-builder

I am working on an application (Cocoa/Objective-c) where I have the blueprint of each floor of a building. I need to be able to click on any room, and print some data about that room. I would also want to highlight the rooms on mouseover.
I have no ideea on how to start doing any of this, so any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSView which I assume is how your handling your UI is a subclass of NSResponder. Which handles all the user events like mouse movements and clicking.

See Apple's documentation of the class http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSResponder

And here is an Apple guide to event handling http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i

Comment: Thanks. Any ideea on how to highlight only one room in an NSImageView?

Comment: Perhaps you could have a NSView with multiple NSImageViews for each room. You could subclass NSImageView and have a method when a mouse is hovering over it to highlight. It really is up to you, there's more than one way to do things. Another option, maybe harder, is to manually check the location of the mouse pointer and based on the location highlight the desired part of the NSImageView.